# has been blocked by CORS policy --why am I getting this error for post request in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

for `GET` request, I got the same error and I fixed that but now for `POST` request again getting this error. For the `GET` request I fixed that by writing this in a startup.cs file. What can I do?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
      builder => {
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:fhfhhfh",
          "https://localhost:fhfhf");
      });
  });

  services.AddControllers();
  services.AddRazorPages();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, GameUserContext db) {
  if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }

  db.Database.EnsureCreated();
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseCors();

  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);


  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the details error message you have faced now?  Which request you have sent to the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change app.UseCors()  to  app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

if it  is still not working

try to change your builder to builder => {
builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:fhfhhfh",
"https://localhost:fhfhf")
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod();
});

Comment: thanks man its working. but still giving the error message in the console and i need to reload to see every request's result :(

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44346/api/User' from origin 'https://localhost:44347' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.spread.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (spread.js:25)

Comment: is this for axios cdn?I added this cdn
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.20.0/axios.min.js

Comment: Check if  add " .AllowCredentials();"  after "AllowAnyMethod()"  will work

Comment: I see in your code above that you are using app.UserCors twice.  Please use only app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins); And another thing - have you tried to use builder.AllowAnyOrigin() instead  of the url list?

Comment: If it still not working please post you java script code calling the APIs. Are you using jquery ajax ore something else? Or maybe you are using c# httpclient? Pls post then the code that creates  the client and sends a request.

Comment: const baseHost = "https://localhost:44346"
      const getallUser = baseHost + '/api/User';
        const topTen = baseHost + '/api/User/TopTen';
        const authToken = {
            headers: {
                
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               
                
            }
        };`

Comment: axios.post(getallUser, authToken).then(function (result) {

Comment: It's the first time I hear about  axios. I need some time to check it For now I am not sure but  you can try to delele comma from " headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',}  "  (after json).

Answer (score 1):

Allow POST method by extending your builder like this:

```
builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:fhfhhfh", "https://localhost:fhfhf")
       .WithMethods("POST", "GET");
```

[WithMethods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.withmethods?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsPolicyBuilder.WithMethods);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Or you can allow any method:

```
builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:fhfhhfh", "https://localhost:fhfhf")
       .AllowAnyMethod();
```

[AllowAnyMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.allowanymethod?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsPolicyBuilder.AllowAnyMethod);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: still not working. Got this error also
spread.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror

Comment: @IsratJerin for now to see if it is cors issue you can change `WithOrigins` method to `AllowAnyOrigin()`, also use `AllowAnyMethod()` and add `AllowAnyHeader()`

Comment: can you help me?